# Problems after upgrading the Navigation library for Compose to Alpha 7

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently using the alpha version of the **Navigation library for Compose**, everything was fine in version 6, but when upgrading to Alpha 7, it seems that I get an error having **AnimatedNavHost** (com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.16.1).

The problem is that now when compiling and running the application in the emulator or on a physical device the app crashes and closes (I understand that because it fails to instantiate or load the AnimatedNavHost).

The log shows me the following error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
    at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost$lambda-3(AnimatedNavHost.kt:323)
    at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:158)
    at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:85)
    at com.jeluchu.inook.core.navigation.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:136)
    at com.jeluchu.inook.core.navigation.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:134)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1$measurables$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1$measurables$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3330)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2577)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2517)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2980)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:259)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:145)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:234)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:231)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:49)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1107)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:231)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:226)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose$ui_release(SubcomposeLayout.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:466)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(BoxWithConstraints.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:64)
```

**Libraries:**

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha07")
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.16.1")
```

**Current implementation:**

```
setContent {

    BoxWithConstraints {
        val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
        AnimatedNavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.Phone.route,
            builder = {
                addPhone(
                    navController = navController,
                    width = constraints.maxWidth / 2
                )
                ...
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
fun NavGraphBuilder.addPhone(
    navController: NavController,
    width: Int,
) {
    composable(
        route = Screen.Phone.route,
        exitTransition = { _, _ ->
            slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { -width },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 500,
                    easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                )
            ) + fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(300))
        },
        popEnterTransition = { initial, _ ->
            slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = { -width },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 500,
                    easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                )
            ) + fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(300))
        },
    ) {
        PhoneMain(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

---

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val arguments: List<NamedNavArgument>) {

    object Phone : Screen(
        route = "phone",
        arguments = emptyList()
    )

...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try update [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/) to `0.17.0`

From the [changelog](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases/tag/v0.17.0) :

> Update to depend on Navigation 2.4.0-alpha07 (#668) @ianhanniballake